# Plug in Separated names by commas/spaces into <li> 's created via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, space

I have a few actor names separated by commas, and I am trying to get each name in that list and plug it into a dynamically created li of its own under a ul while capitalizing the first letter only and trimming commas/spaces (the only space that should not get trimmed is between "john lock" since there is no comma there between the name) like this:

```
var cast = ('jack, kate ,sawyer , john lock ,, hurley')

<ul id="cast-members">
<li>Jack</li>
<li>Kate</li>
<li>Sawyer</li>
<li>John Lock</li>
<li>Hurley</li>
</ul>
```

Any idea how to get this accomplished with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
var cast = 'jack, kate ,sawyer , john lock ,, hurley';
var castlist = cast.split(',');

var $ul = $('<ul>'); //create an in-memory <ul> element to hold our elements

$.each(castlist, function(idx,val){ // for each item in the split array
    var value = $.trim(val).replace(/\b\S/g, function(m){return m.toUpperCase();}); // trim and capitalize the item
    if (value.length > 0){ // if its length > 0 (non-empty)
        var $li = $('<li>', { // create a <li> element
            html: $('<a>', { // set its html to be a new <a> element
                href:'Bio.html#'+value, // with a href
                text:value // and a text value
            })
        });
        $ul.append($li); // append our new <li> to the <ul>
    }
});
$('.lost-cast').append( $ul );  // append the filled <ul> in the /lost-cast element
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gvb6n/

Comment: So I've been trying to implement the demo with the live function, but can't seem to get it to work.                                    demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VzjZD/1/                                  Any idea how to get it to work live? Thank you so far Gaby!

Comment: @Moving, you should read the `cast` and create the `castlist` inside the `click` handler.. demo at **http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/VzjZD/2/**

Comment: Functioning magically:) Any idea how to make the first letter of the names capitalized?

Comment: Besides capitalization, I'm having an issue. I'm trying to add an <a> tag after the <li> before the text to link to their biographies, but it's driving me crazy! Here is my latest attempt fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VzjZD/3/

Comment: @Moving gifts, here is a **[complete solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/gvb6n/)** of what you try to do .. (*added capialization and a link and some comments..*)